# Is the statement "all bounded subsets of countable sets are finite" true?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I was solving a question where I had to state whether the subset of Q in interval [1,3] (Let's call it set B) is finite or not, and it dawned to me that since Q is countable and infinite, it has a bijection with N.

If we take every element of N that correspondence to every element of set B and create a 1-1 correspondence between that subset and another subset of N (Let's call it set A) in the form {1,2,3,...,n} for some n natural number, we can in turn create a bijection between set A and set B.

Meaning that B can be written in the form B = {a1,a2,a3,...,an} such that all elements are listed and n is some natural number. Which is the definition of a non-empty countably finite set in my course.

Is this true? And is the above a reasonable proof? Would this work for interval (1,3) as well?

Comment: It should be obvious that it **isn't** finite: e.g. consider $1.1,1.11,1.111,1.1111,...$ So your "proof" definitely has a flaw somewhere. (HINT: a bijection between $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ won't preserve the ordering ...)

Comment: not every subset of N is finite, so you can't necessarily write A as you did above. e.g. the even numbers form a proper, but still infinite, subset of N.

Comment: Oh God, I suck at this . Thank you for clearing that out .

Answer (score 3):

*Counter-example*:
$$\Bigl\{\,\frac1n\:\Bigm\vert\: n\in\mathbf N^*\,\Bigr\}.$$